# AngularJS promise hangs UI

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My app hangs even though I am using a promise to run calculations.

I'm writing a little BlackJack game in Angular. In this game, I want to display permutations of cards at the bottom of my game board. My game board renders fast when I don't call the `getData()` method (see below) that calculates the permutations. But when I call `getData()` my UI hangs.

The service where I declare and return a promise looks like this:

```
app.service('cardService', ['$q', 'myservice', 'calculation', function ($q,  myservice, calculation) {
    return {
        getData: function () {
            var defer = $q.defer();

            myservice.setup_deck();
            var cards = myservice.get_needed_cards(myservice.player_hand, myservice.static_deck);

            // This is calculation-intensive
            var dh_grouped = calculation.step1(cards);
            var result = calculation.step2(dh_grouped);

            defer.resolve(result);

            return defer.promise;
        }
    };

}]);
```

Now, I call the promise in a very vanilla way like this:

```
// controller.js
$scope.display_calculations = function () {

    cardService.getData().then(function(result){
        $scope.calcs = result;
        console.log('calculations successful'); 
    });
    console.log('this message shows before the one above');
};   

// The relevant HTML
<td ng-repeat="c in calcs">{{c.result}}</td>
```

To debug, I removed the statement `$scope.calcs = result` to see if removing them would stop my UI from hanging:

```
cardService.getData().then(function(result){
    console.log('calculations successful'); 
});
```

**The above did not work. My UI still hangs!** The only way I could prevent the UI from hanging is by not calling `getData()`.

How can I use angular so my expensive operations don't hang the UI?

P.S. I am using Angular 1.2.21 and even tried using 1.5.x but that did not work either.

Comment: Where and how often display_calculations is called? If UI hangs just from a single call, the problem is not related to Angular but to general JS. Expensive calculations should be either made asynchronous or moved to web worker to not block the main thread.

Comment: Yep, so I used $timeout and it worked as DerekMT answered below and  my problem is fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use $timeout

```
app.service('cardService', ['$q', '$timeout', 'myservice', 'calculation', function ($q,  $timeout, myservice, calculation) {
    return {
        getData: function () {
            return $timeout(function() {
               myservice.setup_deck();
               var cards = myservice.get_needed_cards(myservice.player_hand, myservice.static_deck);

               // This is calculation-intensive
               var dh_grouped = calculation.step1(cards);
               return calculation.step2(dh_grouped);
            }, 1);
        }
    };
}]);
```

This will defer the execution and let your UI load first. `$timeout` returns a promise so the rest of your code can stay the same.

Comment: This will let the UI load first, then hang. Might be enough for the OP's case though.

Comment: Yeah, it will have to run eventually. The only other thing to do would be to optimize that slow method.

Comment: It worked! My board displays and nothing is hanging before the results are calculated and returned. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 3):

You might be confusing promises with threads. Promises don't enable concurrent execution. If you need to perform CPU intensive tasks in JavaScript while keeping the UI responsive, you have to either:

- [spawn a WebWorker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers) (browsers)
- [spawn a process](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v6.x/docs/api/child_process.html#child_process_asynchronous_process_creation) (Node.js)
- find a way to split the computations into small chunks and run it chunk by chunk  (so the UI can respond to the user between each chunk)

Comment: Thanks! I will look into it. For this case, using $timeout as DerekMT suggested worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I was working on a embedded system and didn't had GUI refresh issues at all but i was having hang outs while time to time instead (its a physical device so it stays turned on for days/months/years) as @DerekMT12 mentions adding $timeout fixed this behavior

Module

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',['ngRoute']);
```

Service

```
var yourServiceModule = myApp.service('YourService', function ($http) {
    this.your_method = function (a) { return a*a};
});
```

Controller

```
//just wrap your service,http call using $timeout
$timeout(function() {
    //vanilla service call
    YourService.your_method().then(
              function (response) {
                 //console.log("sync_with_cloud: "+ response);
                 $scope.check_cloud_port_statuses_progress=100;
                 //...
             },
              function(data) {
                  // Handle error here

                $rootScope.global_config_1 += "\nError(333): cant connect to cloud at "+Date.now();+"\n\n";
                $scope.check_cloud_port_statuses_progress = -1;
              }
    );

}, 8);
```